# PDO_OCI (Oracle) with persistent connections - any way to set max_persistent, persistent_timeout etc.?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oci8

I am using PHP 7.4 with PDO_OCI extension to connect to Oracle 19c (with Oracle Instant Client on Windows).

It all works fine, however I've noticed that connecting to the database is a bit slow and if I switch to using persistent connections (**PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE**), PHP pages open significantly faster.

My question is: **is this in any way configurable?**

When using standard Oracle OCI8 module, there are such settings in PHP.ini as **oci8.max_persistent**, **oci8.persistent_timeout** or **oci8.ping_interval** that modify the behaviour of persistent connections... is there any equivalent for PDO_OCI? I'm just a bit worried that some bug can cause thousands of zombie connections being created...

Comment: You should be able to change it in your ini file as stated here -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

PDO_OCI isn't as full featured as OCI8.  The generic PDO layer design adds a bit of overhead too.  Overall I'd recommend using OCI8 - there are some simple wrappers that can make it look like PDO, if that helps.

PDO seems to do a ping to the DB every time a script get a persistent connection from the connection cache - the timing is not configurable so it's not ideal for ultimate scalability in active apps.  With OCI8 you can choose the timing.

If your app is connecting as the one DB user I wouldn't worry too much about max_persistent.  The best practice would be to carefully control the number of PHP processes running, since each will have an open connection to the DB.

With both drivers you can set various Oracle Net parameters to configure timeouts, dead connection detection, connection storms, etc.  You may want to look at these.  There is some basic doc [here](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionha) that gives an overview.